# Playing a sound through iPhone from Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

As we get closer to the launch of the Apple Watch I am currently preparing an app for it. However what I want to do is be able to play a sound from the Apple Watch such as a song. Searching around I can see you need to play it through the iPhone but I can't figure out how to actually do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Objective-C is my preferred language however I can work with Swift.

Comment: Is there anyway to play the sound from the watch?

Comment: I have been told you can't. Not sure why they block that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Apple watch can play music , It is not currently possible to play sounds using the latest build of WatchKit.